# Laravel 5: Time Difference Between 2 Dates

Tags: datetime, laravel-5, php-carbon

Is there a way I could get a result like this:

```
Date1 is 1 minute 2 hours 3 days 4 years away from Date2
```

in Laravel 5 + Carbon between two dates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out `Carbon::diffForHumans()` method exists.

Some code for the curious:

```
$date1 = new Carbon();
$diff = $date1->diffForHumans($date2);
print 'Date1 is ' + $diff . ' away from Date2';

// output
// "Date1 is 3 weeks away from Date2"
```

Comment: *.* I don't understand you people downvoting without a single comment.

Comment: You can donate an upvote so other people searching for solution to the same problem would not hesitate to try out the suggested solution.

Comment: @OzanKurt hahaha! You, I like you. :D